# Belongs_to Relationship Giving Errors on Live Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

In my local environment, I can get the names of teens to show up by calling the method as follows however this is not showing up in the live version of the site.  The teen_mid has a belongs_to relationship to a teen.

It's a mongoDB backend so there is no schema.

```
<% @teen_mid.each do |fn| %>  
  <%= fn.teen.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

The error looks like:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass): 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:       7:        <% @teen_end.each do |fn| %> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:       8:            <ul> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:       9:                <li> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:      10:                    <%= link_to fn.teen.full_name, teen_end_year_url(fn.id) %> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:      11:                    <ul> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:      12:                        <li><%= fn.updated_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></li> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:      13:                        <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_teen_end_year_url(fn.id) %></li> 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:    app/views/teen_end_year/index.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_teen_end_year_index_html_erb___2823357747674697580_70015951896080' 
Jun 13 18:24:11 ctjmadrichim app/web.1:    app/views/teen_end_year/index.html.erb:7:in `each'
```

The Teen Model is:

```
class Teen < User

  before_validation :unformat_phone_numbers
  after_validation :format_phone_numbers

  many :teen_mid_year
  many :teen_end_year

  many :admin_interviews

  many :teacher_mid_year
  many :teacher_end_year

  many :incidents

  one  :teen_new
  one  :teen_term

  key  :born_on,     Date
  key  :home_phone,  String
  key  :cell_phone,  String

  validates_length_of :home_phone, :cell_phone, is: 10
```

And the model for the form is:

```
class TeenMidYear
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :teen

  key :placement,            String
  key :aid,                  String
  key :initiative,           String
  key :behave,               String
  key :reliable,             String
  key :srelation,            String
  key :overall_performance,  String
  key :other_teens,          String

  timestamps!
end
```

Comment: Going to need some more information than that. Full class files, schema file, and any errors you're getting would be a great start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem shown in the trace is that `fn.teen` is returning nil. That suggests that there is no `Teen` object associated with the particular `@teen_mid` you have in the loop when the error occurs.

If the `teen` association is essential, I'd suggest adding a validation at creation time to prevent it from coming up nil. If it's not essential, then some guard code around the `link_to` that renders a default string in the association's absence would be a good idea.